# Flex button script

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

In my applications I have to generate a button dynamically and have to keep a click handler for the same. How to write script for clicking button?

I'm using following code for creating button dynamically

```
var btn:Button = new Button;
btn.label = "Print";
```

whats for click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,myfun);
```

write your code in `myfun` function.

Comment: Isn't mxml nice?  click="myfun()" is so much easier to type, and you can control whether you want to bother with an event parameter!  Of course it doesn't help in this dynamic UI case, but non-Flex devs should take notes here.  =)

Answer (score 1):

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick)
```

...

```
private function onClick(evt:MouseEvent)
{
    trace("click");
}
```

[About handling events](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html)